# Excel Vlookup date,

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2013

I have 2 excel sheets 1 which links to an access database and pulls the information from this and 1 which users can enter their work time information in.

I am trying to do some data validation so that if the date has any information for it has information in the database associated with it then it will display that data rather than being 00:00:00 on my other sheet. I have simplified this to the same sheet for now till i can get it working

I have tried =VLOOKUP(K1,A:I,4,FALSE) which shows #N/A

where K1 is the date i am searching for, I have attached the image of my table which refreshes on load.

My end goal is to have it search for the date(kpi_date) and the name(ad_name) and display the information in each column.

Any help is much appreciated

Kind Regards

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDOjO.png

Comment: Now that i reread this , you want to search for 2 pieces of data or 1? my answer below searches for date and returns adname

Comment: My end result will be both the date and name to display enq_time - Total_hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely want

```
=VLOOKUP(K1,B:C,2,FALSE)
```

> `=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`
>
> `lookup_value`  = the value you want to search with and for
>
> `table_array` = the data you want to search in, the most left column is used to >look for the date in - ie (col B)and the rest of the columns can be used as a >return value(col C in your example)
>
> `col_index_num` = the column you want to return for the table_array as an index >of the table , column 2 of the table_array
>
> `[range_lookup]` = optional (TRUE if omitted) TRUE will take the nearest match >in the most left column (sorted table is needed to work accurately)  set to >FALSE for an exact match to be found(sort not needed)

in all circumstances the first row found from the top is the one thats used to get the return value from even if mutiple values exist in col B

Comment: so you want to search both date and name and return the entire row of data or multiple pieces anyway?

Comment: My end result will be search for both the date and name to display enq_time (and till the end of the table) Sorry for the multiple questions its been bugging me for the past 3 days trying to solve it. Thanks

Comment: can you add a helper column (an extra columns with the formula =B2&C2 that will make a ref we can search for in 1 cell), otherwise you cant use VLOOKUP and you will need to use INDEX/MATCH

Comment: Thanks ill use the index match option for now till i learn more about excel > access data manipulation.

Comment: if you need help you can mail me at stevenmartin99@gmail.com